# iOS:Moving from custom view to tab bar view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I had one custom view named `pharmacyviewcontroller` that comes when one button is clicked on the `tabbarview`. When the subview appears sub contains one button and when i clicked that button it should navigate to the 3rd TabBarViewController.

My problem is when the button on the tab view is clicked custom view appears and when i clicked the button over the custom view its moving to 3rd tab bar view controller but the tabbar button and navigation bar disappears.My code is as below for the custom view button clicked to move to the 3rd tabbar controller

```
- (IBAction)phok:(id)sender{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];    
    saveViewController *secondViewController = (saveViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"saveview"];
    [self.navigationController  presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    self.view.window.rootViewController=secondViewController;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will work perfectly now. I have tested it thoroughly.

```
- (IBAction)vc1Button:(UIButton *)sender{
    //THIS IS THE ONLY LINE OF CODE NEEDED UNLESS PASSING DATA
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

}
```

Ensure that you use 0 as the number 1. This should do the trick.

**INCORRECT FOR TAB BAR**

You are modally presenting (`presentViewController` is the updated code from pre iOS 6 of `modallyPresentViewController`). Modally presenting is part of the issue initially, pushing maintains the hierarchy of navigation.

```
[self.navigationController  pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

In your code you have a function trying to perform after changing views you have:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController=secondViewController;
```

This line is stating that you are trying to make `secondViewController` as the root. Why is this there?

Comment: if i keep the above line nothing happens the view is not moving to destination

Comment: @iosdeveloper so if you remove your root view call nothing happens?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using that line of code? Do you have navigation controller as well as tab bar?

Comment: @iosdeveloper I have solved your question. We were both wrong. Please check update.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
self.view.window.rootViewController=secondViewController;
```

will replace everything with the secondViewController so the tab view will be covered. Take this line out and the rest should work. Your root should not be the secondViewController which is a section in your tab view but the tab view itself. (from what I understand your layout to be)